# Laravel : Cannot show many to many relationships in view

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, relational-database, relationship

I cannot show many to many relationships in view
It's relationships of Art objects and Exhibitions.
I have many Art objects in many exhibitions table.
But It doesn't show in view when I call.

In Model:

**Exhibition Model:**

```
class Exhibition extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'exhibitions';
    protected $fillable = ['Ex_id','Name','Start_date','End_date','Limit_visit','picture'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'Ex_id';

    public function ExhibitionHasUser(){
        return $this->belongsTo(ExhibitionHasUser::class,'Ex_id', 'exhibition_id');
    }
}
```

**ExhibitionHasArt Model**

```
class ExhibitionHasArt extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'exhibition_has_art_objs';
    protected $fillable = ['list_no','exhibition_id','art_obj_Id_no'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'list_no';

    public function Exhibition(){
        return $this->hasMany(Exhibition::class,'exhibition_id');
    }

    public function Art_obj(){
        return $this->hasMany(Art_obj::class,'Id_no');
    }
}
```

**Art_obj Model**

```
class Art_obj extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'art_objs';
    protected $fillable = ['Id_no','Type_of_art','Type_of_coll','Picture'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'Id_no';


    public function ExhibitionHasArt(){
        return $this->belongsTo(ExhibitionHasArt::class,'Id_no', 'art_obj_Id_no');
    }


}
```

**In ExhibitionController**

```
 public function show($Ex_id)
    {
        $exhibitions = Exhibition::find($Ex_id);
        $exhibitionHasArts = ExhibitionHasArt::with('Art_obj')->get();
        return view('Exhibition.ShowExhibition', compact('exhibitions','exhibitionHasArts')); 
    }
```

In view: I want to show the exhibition that finds from the primary key and shows art object that shows in this exhibition.

```
<h1>Exhibition: {{$exhibitions->Ex_id}}</h1>
            <h2>Art objects in this exhibition</h2>
            <br>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped"> 
                <tr>
                    <td>exhibition_id</td>
                    <td>art_obj_Id_no</td>
                    <td>Title</td>
                </tr>
                @foreach($exhibitionHasArts as $row) 
                @if($row->exhibition_id == $exhibitions->Ex_id)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$row->exhibition_id}}</td>
                        <td>{{$row->art_obj_Id_no}}</td>
                        <td>{{$row->Art_obj->Title}}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endif
                @endforeach 
            </table>
```

But It doesn't work.

In table exhibition_has_art_objs
[image]

Comment: I think you should use `belongsToMany` if your relationship is `many to many`.

Answer (score 1):

you should change your relations like that if you really like to get the data from pivot table

> *please let me know if i am wrong.*

**Exhibition Model:**

```
class Exhibition extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'exhibitions';
    protected $fillable = ['Ex_id','Name','Start_date','End_date','Limit_visit','picture'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'Ex_id';

    public function ExhibitionHasUser(){
        return $this->hasMany(ExhibitionHasUser::class,'exhibition_id','Ex_id');
    }
}
```

**ExhibitionHasArt Model**

```
class ExhibitionHasArt extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'exhibition_has_art_objs';
    protected $fillable = ['list_no','exhibition_id','art_obj_Id_no'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'list_no';

    public function Exhibition(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Exhibition::class,'exhibition_id', 'Ex_id');
    }

    public function Art_obj(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Art_obj::class,'art_obj_Id_no', 'Id_no');
    }
}
```

**Art_obj Model**

```
class Art_obj extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'art_objs';
    protected $fillable = ['Id_no','Type_of_art','Type_of_coll','Picture'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'Id_no';


    public function ExhibitionHasArt(){
        return $this->hasMany(ExhibitionHasArt::class,'art_obj_Id_no','Id_no');
    }
}
```

Comment: It says `Trying to get property 'Title' of non-object`

Comment: what is the output when you place dd($exhibitionHasArts->toArray()) in your controller after eloquent

Comment: please check current script. problem was in foreign key and owner key mention

Comment: when I use 
public function Exhibition(){
        return $this->hasMany(Exhibition::class,'exhibition_id', 'Ex_id');
    }

     public function Art_obj(){
        return $this->hasMany(Art_obj::class,'art_obj_Id_no', 'Id_no');
    }
dd($exhibitionHasArts->toArray()) show https://uppic.cc/d/7jT But It not show in view

Comment: so whats the output now in dd ?

Comment: look like you are getting the data with relations. so whats the problem now ? is there any exception showing ?

Comment: also remove the unnecessary condition in blade : @if($row->exhibition_id == $exhibitions->Ex_id)

Comment: It says :: Property [Title] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\museum-DB-Project\resources\views\Exhibition\ShowExhibition.blade.php)

Comment: in my answer i mentioned that you should add belongsTo relation not hasMany in your ExhibitionHasArt Model

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183278/discussion-between-emtiaz-zahid-and-kunjanaphorn-boonmak).

Comment: Now it works but I use 
`public function Exhibition(){
        return $this->hasMany(Exhibition::class,'Ex_id');
    }

    public function Art_obj(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Art_obj::class,'art_obj_Id_no');
    }`
in ExhibitionHasArt model
and use 
`public function ExhibitionHasUser(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(ExhibitionHasUser::class,'Ex_id', 'exhibition_id');
    }`
in Exhibition model
then the last I use 
`public function ExhibitionHasArt(){
        return $this->hasMany(ExhibitionHasArt::class,'Id_no', 'art_obj_Id_no');
    }`
In Art_obj model

Answer (score 0):

In your case, there's **no need** to define **ExhibitionHasArt**. 
[From laravel many to many documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

*What I tried here is modifying your codes directly, only for expressing the logic of many-to-many, so you may have to debug them and to fit your database yourself.*

**In Models**:

```
class Exhibition extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'exhibitions';
    //While the primary key of a table is set auto increasing, it doesn't need to be fillable.
    protected $fillable = [/*'Ex_id'*/,'Name','Start_date','End_date','Limit_visit','picture'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'Ex_id';

    public function art_objs() {
        //use "belongsToMany" instead of "belongsTo".
        return $this->belongsToMany(Art_obj::class, 'exhibition_has_art_objs', 'exhibition_id', 'art_obj_id_no');
    }
}

class Art_obj extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'art_objs';
    //The primary key of a table is usually set auto increasing, no need to be fillable.
    protected $fillable = [/*Id_no, */'Type_of_art','Type_of_coll','Picture']; 
    protected $primaryKey = 'Id_no';

    public function exhibitions() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Exhibition::class,'exhibition_has_art_objs', 'art_obj_id_no', 'exhibition_id');
    }
}
```

**In ExhibitionController**:

```
public function show($Ex_id)
{
    $exhibition = Exhibition::find($Ex_id);
    return view('Exhibition.ShowExhibition', compact('exhibition')); 
}
```

**In View**:

```
<h1>Exhibition: {{$exhibition->Ex_id}}</h1>
<h2>Art objects in this exhibition</h2>
<br>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped"> 
    <tr>
        <td>exhibition_id</td>
        <td>art_obj_Id_no</td>
        <td>Title</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach($exhibition->art_objs as $art_obj) 
        <tr>
            <td>{{$exhibition->Ex_id}}</td>
            <td>{{$art_obj->Id_no}}</td>
            <td>{{$art_obj->Type_of_art}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach 
</table>
```

Comment: trust me, my way is much easier.